# Integrate readline's kill-ring and the X11 clipboard

Tags: unix, zsh, clipboard, zsh-zle

In my `.zshrc`, I use the following snippet to integrate the shell's clipboard and my primary X11 clipboard. Thanks to this integration, I can cut-and-paste text to and from emacs, firefox, and the terminal without having to use the mouse.

```
kill-line() { zle .kill-line ; echo -n $CUTBUFFER | xclip -i }
zle -N kill-line # bound on C-k

yank() { LBUFFER=$LBUFFER$(xclip -o) }
zle -N yank # bound on C-y
```

Note: I use this trick on mac os x as well (with pbcopy/pbpaste instead of xclip) and thanks to [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) my two computers share a single clipboard. Neat. But it doesn't work with readline. And I find myself using readline quite often, for example in (i)python, in gdb, in ncftp...

So here comes my question: **is there a way to integrate readline's clipboard with the-rest-of-the-world ?**

Of course, I'm thinkging about some `.inputrc` wizardry here, but any insight/ideas would be welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure what you really want here but I found another tool like xclip
XSEL - http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/ which seems more powerful

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Actually, what I'm after is a way to call a program like XSEL automatically from readline programs (e.g. bash) when I press Ctrl-K / Ctrl-Y. I guess this comes down to binding shell command to readline key combinations...

Comment: I'd suggest you change your `echo -n` to `print -rn --` (or `printf %s`) above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I run everything inside [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).  This gives me tons of functionality across all terminal-based programs, not just readline-based ones.  It has its own paste buffer(s), which are shared between all screens in your current session, and can read/write an exchange file (configurable with `bufferfile`).

- A screen selection is made with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd>, <*movement*>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <*movement*>;
- copied to the paste buffer with <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
- pasted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>;
- replaced by the contents of the exchange file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd><</kbd>;
- and written out to the exchange file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd>.

Then all you need are little helpers to synchronize `/tmp/screen-exchange` and the X selection.  Something as simple as this would work.

```
# ~/.screenrc (or entered at C-a : command prompt)
bind '{' exec sh -c 'xclip -o>~/.screen_exchange'
bind '}' exec sh -c 'xclip -i ~/.screen_exchange'
```

Of course some nicer bindings and macros would make life easier (this requires `C-a { C-a < C-a ]` to paste X selection to the terminal), but it's completely up to you.

Answer (score 16):

Bash 4.0 introduces some new functionality:

> [NEWS](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS)
>
> The command assigned to a key sequence with ``bind -x`' now sets two new
>   variables in the environment of the executed command:  `READLINE_LINE_BUFFER`
>   and `READLINE_POINT`.  The command can change the current readline line
>   and cursor position by modifying `READLINE_LINE_BUFFER` and `READLINE_POINT`,
>   respectively.

The `NEWS` file seems to be inaccurate; `READLINE_LINE` (no `_BUFFER`) is what's documented elsewhere and actually works.

The following will simulate the behavior of Bash's existing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+(<kbd>U</kbd>|<kbd>K</kbd>|<kbd>Y</kbd>) but affecting the X selection, though I use <kbd>Meta</kbd>/<kbd>Esc</kbd> because I don't like overwriting existing functionality.

```
_xdiscard() {
    echo -n "${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}" | xclip
    READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
    READLINE_POINT=0
}
_xkill() {
    echo -n "${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}" | xclip
    READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}"
}
_xyank() {
    READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}$(xclip -o)${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
}
bind -m emacs -x '"\eu": _xdiscard'
bind -m emacs -x '"\ek": _xkill'
bind -m emacs -x '"\ey": _xyank'
```

I still like `screen` more, but this better answers your question — as long as the only readline application you care about is Bash.

Comment: thanks ; this is indeed the kind of stuff I wanted. Unfortunately, I'm using zsh as a shell, so when I use readline it is often with _other_ programs than bash :-) I guess I'll have to get used to screen.

Comment: this is not working for me under bash 4.2.37. Those variables actually do not contain any value.

Comment: I up-voted this answer and user @Wei_Hu's modification below. See there.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to propose the following `_xyank()` function based on ephemient's answer:

```
_xyank() {
    CLIP=$(xclip -o)
    COUNT=$(echo -n "$CLIP" | wc -c)
    READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}${CLIP}${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
    READLINE_POINT=$(($READLINE_POINT + $COUNT))
}
```

What this does is to move the cursor to the end of yanked text, making it more consistent with other built-in commands.

Comment: thanks as well, but again, my question was for non-bash readline applications :-)

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51933/zsh-copy-and-paste-like-emacs/219678#219678), I found it can be nicer to have separate keybindings to populate the X clipboard, this is because I often use "kill" for text manipulation in Readline, and I don't want this to wipe out the clipboard each time.

When Readline ever gets the ability to have keybindings which trigger interactions with X, I'd recommend binding ^Xw and ^Xy to copy and paste.

I know this doesn't provide a solution to your question, but I don't have enough rep to say it in a comment.

As for extending Readline with the ability to bind keys to commands, I brought it up on the Readline mailing list, we'll see what Chet says:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-readline/2016-05/msg00002.html