# Tmux equivalent of ctrl+k (copy current pos -> eol into buffer)

Tags: terminal, key-bindings, hotkeys, tmux

I have been using tmux for some time now and really like the internal copy buffer. I frequently find myself wanting to copy a command between panes but haven't really found an easy way of doing this.

What I would like is some equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> that moves the data into the tmux buffer. Is there any way of doing this with one key binding? As it is, I could probably get it to work with two (first do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then a keybinding that via xclip moves clipboard into tmux buffer), but I really would like to be able to do it quickly with just one hotkey.

EDIT:
I am running bash as shell in tmux, with evilvte as terminal in Kubuntu 12.04.

Comment: It sounds like you want C-k (or some other “hotkey”) in your shell to automatically load the killed text into a *tmux* buffer. You can arrange this with the `echo 'some text' | tmux load-buffer -` or `tmux set-buffer 'some text'`, but shell integration depends on which shell you are using. Please update your question to indicate which shell you are using (and tag for the shell). See [this other SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1088763/193688) for integrating Bash 4+ with *xclip* (you would use `tmux load-buffer -` and `tmux save-buffer -` instead of `xclip` and `xclip -o`).

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen: Added some more info. Thanks for the link, I think I should be able to work out how to do it with that info.